# Spring boot - Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to learn Spring, I'm building a project using Netbeans, I used Srping Initializr to get all files ready but when I try to run the project I get this error 'Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver ' Event though the driver is set up, I have the dependencies on the POM file as well as the project's properties, can you please take a look?

This is the error message:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-11-20 20:58:28.978 ERROR 10340 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:801) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:536) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1160) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:911) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) [spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:409) [spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) [spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1289) [spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at com.egg.biblioteca.BibliotecaApplication.main(BibliotecaApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:633) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:911) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver 
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97) ~[spring-core-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:175) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:125) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:48) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:90) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
36 common frames omitted
```

This is the POM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.17</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.egg</groupId>
    <artifactId>biblioteca</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>biblioteca</name>
    <description>Proyecto de biblioteca Egg</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And these are the properties:

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DATABASE?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&use
Timezone=true&serverTimezone=GMT&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username: root
spring.datasource.password: root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver 
spring.jpa.show-sql: true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.thymeleaf.cache: false
```

I tried changing the version of the Mysql driver on the dependencies inside the pom.xml but doesn't seem to work. I've reviewed the driver version and everything seems to be working ok.

I'm running springboot version 2.7.17, Java version 8 and the current Mysql driver is 8.0.33.

Comment: Looking at your config it looks like there is a trailing space after the `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` name. Make sure there isn't. Or you could just remove the `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` as Spring will automatically detect the proper driver based on the URL.

Comment: Try without `runtime `scope for mysql dependency.

Comment: I agree with @M.Deinum completely. You don't need to add driver-class-name explicitly. Spring is smart enough to detect the driver class by looking at the jar and url.

Comment: Thanks to @M.Deinum and Troley. It was the freaking trailing space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @M. Deinum specified in the comment, you have an extra trailing space in the driver setup property line.

So try changing:
`spring.datasource.driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

To this:
`spring.datasource.driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

And it should work.

Answer (score -1):

You only added JPA dependency. You need to also add sql driver dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The driver is already in the `pom.xml` if you look properly.